# How to free memory space of an image after capturing and processing in python and opencv?

Tags: opencv, python-2.7

In the following code,after capturing and processing some images, this code occupy around 80% of main memory and then terminate automatically by OS.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
num = 1
RED_MIN=np.array([170,160,60],np.uint8)
RED_MAX=np.array([180,255,255],np.uint8)
while True:
    flag, img = capture.read()
    flag=capture.set(3,640)
    flag=capture.set(4,480)
    cv2.imwrite('pic.jpg', img)
    img1=cv2.imread('pic.jpg')
    img=cv2.blur(img1,(3,3))
    hsv_img=cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    frame_thresh=cv2.inRange(hsv_img,RED_MIN,RED_MAX)
        contours,hierarchy=cv2.findContours(frame_thresh,cv2.RETR_LIST,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    x_area=0
    print num
    num=num+1
    if num == 500:
        del(capture)
```

I used capture.release() in each iteration but unable to free space. When the value of num reaches to 500, it only releases the camera not main memory space that can be seen on terminal using top command.How can I free memory space after processing each image?

Comment: are you using [opencv30](http://code.opencv.org/issues/3470) ?

Comment: oh, maybe put the `flag=capture.set(3,640)` lines before the loop ?

Comment: Yup, thank. The problem is solved.

Comment: just out of curiosity, what was it ?